# Export file as palleted 8bit per pixel BMP from GIMP

Tags: gimp

Is it possible to export file as palleted 8bit per pixel BMP from GIMP?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Yes, in GIMP you can save an image as an indexed BMP, it's a quite simple operation.

If your image isn't indexed, you can convert it to [Indexed mode](http://docs.gimp.org/en/gimp-image-convert-indexed.html) before saving:

[image: Convert to Indexed mode]

A dialog appears, and you can use it to choose the preferred depth of the image:

[image: Conversion dialog]

8 bit image means `256 colors` (2^8=256). You can let the program generate an optimal palette or you can reduce the number of colors or use your own palette. The palette could be modified afterwards.

The image could be saved using `File->Export...`, choosing path, file name and writing *bmp* as extension:

[image: Save as BMP]

When you confirm, an export option windows appears:

[image: Export options]

If you are unsure, leave the defaults and press *Export*.